# ASP.NET Identity not adding password to created users

Tags: asp.net, f#, asp.net-identity

I'm doing my own implementation of `IUserPasswordStore<TUser,TKey>` and reading and creation operations are working ok. With the exception that the `UserManager.Create(TUser,Password)` overload does not add any password. I'm a bit uncertain on how it is supposed to be implemented, I would have guessed that the overload would invoke `IUserPasswordStore.CreateAsync` and then `IUserPasswordStore.SetPasswordHashAsync` but that does not seem to be the case. It will just invoke the former method and it won't set the password even when using the overload to provide the password.

Here is my implementation of `IUser<TKey>`:

```
[<AllowNullLiteral>]
type ApplicationUser(id, email) =
    member __.Id = id
    member __.Email = email
    member val PasswordHash = Unchecked.defaultof<string> with get,set
    new(email) = ApplicationUser(0, email)
    interface IUser<int> with
        member __.Id = id
        member val UserName = email with get,set
```

And the `IUserPasswordStore.CreateAsync` simply runs this query against the database:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Users(Email,PasswordHash) VALUES (@email, @pwHash)
```

Comment: Which method are you asking about? I can see a method called [`CreateAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497606.aspx), but no `Create` method...

Comment: @MarkSeemann [Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497484%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) is a non-async extension method.